# Recommendation "to optimize the response time of an SQL query"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, view, query-optimization

I would like to know what are the best solutions to optimize the response time of an SQL query for a table containing more than 2.000.000 records

As a solution, I thought of a virtual table by creating a SQL view (In fact, I prefer mysql to search early in the lines created this year because the data of this application is based on the season.)

Is there a better solution or recommendation?

eg to search all rent lines of rent 12

before => 
select * from rent_lines Where rent_id = 12

Now => 
  I created a view

```
CREATE VIEW v_rent_lines
AS SELECT rent_id, category_id, customer_id, amount ..
Where rent_lines FROM created_at > = (select starts_on from seasons where current = true)

select * from v_rent_lines Where rent_id = 12
```

Notes:

- database engine is being used InnoDB
- I added indexes table (index_rent_lines_on_rent_id, index_rent_lines_on_category_id, index_rent_lines_on_customer_id)
- rent has many rent_lines

Comment: We need more details to work with. Show us the query in question. Give us the schema of the tables involved.

Comment: This really depends on your database structure, and on the queries you want to perform. Also: "what is the best X" questions tend to be closed here, as they don't have exact answers and lead to endless discussions. Please try to make your question more specific.

Comment: Generally simplest solution is to add indexes and to enable sql engine cache (for example query cache) but it applies only to SELECT queries. Answer is not so simple if you have SELECT/INSERT ratio of less than 1000/1.

Comment: I added other information thx

Comment: @SlimTekaya We still need to see a schema and indexes.

Comment: Why don't you create archive table and leave information related to the current season ? I guess that you don't need to have other elements on the same table ?

Comment: Use SQL indexes, it should really help on lookup time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is not really helping anything in this case.  Views primarily help you, as a developer, by letting you refer to a more complex query by name rather than having to repeat the details all the time.  They don't really help mysql all that much.

You have a lot of options.

1. If you don't yet, ensure that you have an index where rent_id is either the only field in the index, or the first field in the index.   For example:

   ```
   create index rent_id_idx on rent_lines (rent_id)
   ```
2. You can consider using mysql's partitioning system and partitioning on rent_id
3. You can create an index that will have a lower cardinality by doing something like:

   ```
   alter table rent_lines add rent_id_bucket smallint unsigned not null after rent_id;
   update rent_lines set rent_id_bucket = rent_id>>16;
   alter table rent_lines add key rent_id_bucket_idx(rent_id_bucket);
   ```

   This will let you do a query like:

   ```
   select * from rent_lines where rent_id_bucket = 16>>16 and rent_id=16
   ```